# Takes 10 seconds to import python modules

Tags: python, performance, import

I came across a problem when starting up my python application. Every now and then (it's really random, a second ago everything worked fine, and now it happens) when I launch the app many module imports take about 10 seconds

Here is an excerpt from the log I get with `python -X importtime my_app.py`

```
...
import time: 1958 | 1958 | PyQt5.QtPositioning
import time: 4192 | 4192 | PyQt5.QtLocation
import time: 27015 | 27015 | PyQt5.QtQuick
import time: 10188068 | 10188068 | PyQt5.QtQuick3D
import time: 10067480 | 10067480 | PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets
import time: 10090626 | 10090626 | PyQt5.QtRemoteObjects
import time: 10115549 | 10115549 | PyQt5.QtSensors
import time: 10065570 | 10065570 | PyQt5.QtSerialPort
...
```

It is not only PyQt5 specific, same for numpy, scipy, pandas, etc.
I have to wait up to an hour, but next time the app will start as usual. These 10 seconds look like some system/python timeout...

I tried to clean up PYTHONPATH variable, leaving only essential paths, tried to remove __pycache__ folders, reboot machine, change code location, checked if there are any specific system tasks running that would clean up a cache, etc. Nothing helps, just waiting.

Any ideas?

The system is: Windows 10, Python 3.9.8

Thanks!

Comment: 10s sounds like a lot! Do you have any other apps running concurrently that make intensive use of the disk? Any memory shortage that results in RAM content being written to the disk?

Comment: This is very likely to be due to a slow spinning disk or one that has issue. You can profile the performance using the Windows resource monitor and check the applications using your disk. What mainly matters is the activity time (related to IOPS). You can even check which files may be the source of the problem (generally too many files are read). It might eventually be due to a bad Python configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - I doubt it is due to the intensive disk use, I checked disk use while my app was loading - disk usage was about 1% (besides, I got SSD) and 30% of RAM used. There is something else, what concerns me is that the delays are around 10 seconds, it does look like a timeout, could it be that modules are doing something with network while importing (I know, it sounds weird, but I have no ideas left)